# "subject and the verb be omission" in a subordinate clause

Tags: sentence-structure

I've learned that after subordinate conjunctions such as "when" or " while", a subject and a verb "be" in a subordinate clause can be omitted when the subject matches the one in the main clause.

Let me take an example.

> She felt rewarded, not when she was awarded the first prize, but when she was praised for her performance by the other contestants.

> She felt rewarded, not when she was awarded the first prize, but when praised for her performance by the other contestants.

> She felt rewarded, not when awarded the first prize, but when she was praised for her performance by the other contestants.

I wonder if the last two sentences are grammatically accurate and semantically understandable.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners Jimmy! On this site, we expect people asking questions to have done some research into their question and tell us how what you found didn't meet your needs. Have you done any searching already? What are you still confused about?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the first one where the subject is not omitted is the most natural. The other two are not necessarily wrong, you'll still be perfectly understood but they sound a little awkward.

If you want to omit the subject you should reverse the sentence order like "When praised for her performance and awarded first prize, she felt rewarded".